# System of initial value problems with initial conditions at different $t_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

In all the references I checked the standard initial value problem for an ODE is stated as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} 
y'=F(y,t)\\
y(t_0)=y_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for some $F:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and under hypotheses on $F$ one can conclude existence, uniqueness, etc.

My question is: is there a standard way to address the problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} 
y'=F(y,t)\\
y_i(t_i)=y_{0,i}, \quad i=1,\ldots, n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where the "initial condition" is not given for the **same** $t_0$ for all the components of $y$, but at different $t_is$? where by address I mean, to begin with, check existence and uniqueness conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $y^{\prime\prime}=-y$ has general solutions $y=C\sin(t)+D\cos(t)$. Even though your question is about first order ODE, since it allow $y$ to be vector we can convert this problem into a first order vector ODE where the components are $y$ and $\dot{y}$

So the initial value problem $y(0)=0$ has general solutions $y=C\sin(t)$. In particular, for all such solutions, $y^{\prime}(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$. When converted to the first order vector ODE, this mean $\dot{y}(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$. So the initial value problem with different starting points $y(0)=0,\dot{y}(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$, in particular, is unsolvable.

Hopefully this explains why existence of solution is not a simple matter when you have different starting points for different coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! that is a nice example. What I am looking for is if there are conditions under which more can be said